# How to Make an OS X Style Search in XHTML/CSS

Tags: css, macos, search, xhtml

Any way to make a OS X Finder "like" but valid XHTML/CSS search textfield with an X to the right, etc.? Even if it only shows up on Safari but degrades that would be fine. I've seen a couple of examples but they seem very complicated.

Comment: Yes. I don't know how the OS X Finder looks like, but you can design anything with HTML/CSS and a little JS if you really need to.

Comment: At the very least you might want to show us a *picture*, and maybe some code to show what you're working with?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're OK with supporting only the newest WebKit-based browser, you can use the new HTML5 feature like this:

```
<form>
  <input name="q" type="search">
  <input type="submit" value="Find">
</form>
```

That's it, no CSS, no Javascript or whatever! 
See an excellent discussion [here](http://diveintohtml5.info/forms.html).

Comment: +1 for the fascinating link. I hadn't come across the new `form` possibilities offered by html 5 until now. =)